# Possible to get longitude latitude from map in Arcgis runtime SDK Java?

Tags: java, javafx, gis, arcgis, arcgis-runtime

I am making a basic JavaFX Map application with Arcgis runtime version 100.3.0. One feature of the application is to display the longitude and latitude information when the mouse is clicked on a certain point on the map. I have looked around for support a lot on Arcgis forum and Javadoc but all methods were taking long lat information as arguments and none were returning them. Is there a possible way to get this information through Arcgis runtime?

I am totally new to GIS programming, so I am sorry if the question is immature.

Thank-you.

Comment: mapView.screenToLocation maybe? Note that I never used ArcGis, just scanned the api/documentation ..

Comment: You need [GeoView#screenToLocation()](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/latest/api-reference/reference/com/esri/arcgisruntime/mapping/view/MapView.html#screenToLocation(javafx.geometry.Point2D)) and maybe [Callout](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/latest/api-reference/reference/com/esri/arcgisruntime/mapping/view/Callout.html). @kleopatra was right for that. `MapView` is implementing class of `GeoView`.

Answer (score 0):

This example takes a mouse click and reports the lat/lon in a callout:
https://developers.arcgis.com/java/latest/sample-code/show-callout.htm

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.